# PHP Zip Archive - open or extractTo is not working

Tags: php, zip

I'm completely at a loss for explaining why this isn't working. HELP!

```
$archive = "x.zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$res = $zip->open($archive);

if ($res === 'TRUE') {
    $unzip_success= $zip->extractTo('/temp/', "inscriptions.txt")

    $zip->close();
}
```

- the target dir "temp" is "0777" permissions
- the code obtained from $res is "11" and not "TRUE" as required by the documentation on PHP.net
- note: must put the full url for $archive and the first argument of extractTo

Comment: Thanks hardik, for anyone interested I'm using,                    system("unzip x.zip inscriptions.txt -d temp");  and it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if nothing works then check if your server is linux.
if its linux you can run unzip command to unzip your file via php's system/exec function.
i.e

```
system("unzip archive.zip");
```

to extract specific file you can check man docs for unzip. many times due to server parameters zip library doesn't work as expected in that cases i switch back to linux commands.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are quoting `TRUE`, which is a keyword and should be left without single quotes. Plus, you could check if the file exists in the zip archive prior to its extraction with [locateName](http://php.net/ziparchive.locatename):

```
$archive = "x.zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$res = $zip->open($archive);

if ($res === true && $zip->locateName('inscriptions.txt') !== false) {
    $unzip_success= $zip->extractTo('/tmp/', "inscriptions.txt");

    $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: I lifted the quotes, but '11' is still not equal to TRUE, so it still fails.  I don't think it is opening the archive but there is no error code for 11 all of the error codes start with 'ER_'.

Comment: Actually there is a error code for 11. `ZIPARCHIVE::ER_OPEN` is a constant whose value is `11`, so there you go: the file could not be opened.

In my end worked fine, does the have the correct permissions?

Answer (score 2):

ZipArcive::extractTo is case-sensitive. If file's name to be extracted do not meet zipped one exactly, the method returns false.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, I have fixed this :)
Use  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for url.
My code  (codeigniter):

```
$this->load->library('unzip');
$file = $this->input->GET('file');
$this->unzip->extract($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/TRAS/application/uploads/' .    $file,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/TRAS/application/views/templates/' . $file);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$res` is equal to 11, that means that `ZipArchive` can't open the specified file.

To test this:

```
$archive = "x.zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$res = $zip->open($archive);

if($res == ZipArchive::ER_OPEN){
    echo "Unable to open $archive\n";
}
```

Comment: Okay, so we know the error code is ER_OPEN, now any suggestions why that might be?  The file is there, are all zip files not created equal?

Comment: Are you sure you have permissions to read the file? Is the path to the file correct (is it in the same dir as the script)? Can you create another zip and test on that? It could be any number of things ...

Comment: I tried changing the permission to 0777, didn't work.  Using another zip in the same dir doesn't work either, same error.

Comment: In the few tests I just did, I got error 11 when either the file did not exist (or path to the file was wrong), or the script did not have read access to the file.

Comment: Your if statement will be true even if `$res` is `true`. Because `var_dump(true == 11)` is `true`. Your if statement should be `if ($res === ZipArchive::ER_OPEN) {`

Answer (score 1):

Adding document root is what worked for me as well.  here is my code

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
        if ($zip->open($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$folder.$file_path) === TRUE) {
            $zip->extractTo($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/$folder');
            $zip->close();
            echo 'ok';
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I meet same problem, but I can open the zip file, it returns `true` after open.

My issue is I got false after `$zip->extractTo()`.

I finally success after delete files named in CHINESE (NO-ENGILISH) in the zip file.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem on Windows 10. The only solution I found was just to try extractTo twice, even though the open() was successful:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($open === true) {
    $result = $zip->extractTo($destination);
    if ($result === false) {
        $result = $zip->extractTo($destination);
    }
    $zip->close();
}
```

The fact that the second extractTo() works (with no intervening action) would seem to indicate that there's nothing wrong with the archive or the destination directory.